# Perfect Square and Multiple question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The population of a village is a perfect square. Later, with an increase of 100, the population was 1 more than a perfect square. Now with an additional increase of 100, the population is again a perfect square. What is the multiple of the original population?
My progress:

Let $x$ as the original population, so that $\sqrt{x}$ Is a perfect square. What should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$a^2+100=b^2+1\iff b^2-a^2=(b-a)(b+a)=99$$

$$b-a=\frac{99}{b+a}$$ which must be a positive integer

Check if their values satisfy the last condition?

Comment: What about $c$? Isn't  $c^2 = (b^2+1) + 100$?

Comment: @user108104, As $99=11\cdot3^2,$ we shall have multiple sets of $(a,b)$ We need to find which $b$ satisfies your last condition

Comment: I got $b=10$ and $a=1$ which satisifes my last condition.

Comment: @user108104, I got $a=49, 49^2+100=50^2+1=2501,2501+100=51^2\implies c=51 $

Answer (score 0):

HINT: I should let the original population be $a^2$, the next population $b^2+1$ and the third population ...

This is a better choice than $x$ because it avoids unnecessary square roots.

Then follow the algebra and see what emerges - there is a basic identity involving squares which will come in handy.

---

So we have (per comment) $$b^2-a^2=(b+a)(b-a)=99=3^2\times 11$$and $$c^2-b^2=(c+b)(c-b)=101$$

In the second case $101$ is prime, which reduces the number of cases, so this is the place to start. Note that we must have that one of $b,c$ is even and the other odd to get two odd factors, and similarly for $a,b$ from the first equation. So $a$ and $c$ have the same parity.

There is also $$c^2-a^2=200=2^3\times 5^2$$

which could have been useful if $200$ had fewer factors. Note that the difference between two even squares is never divisible by $8$ but not $16$. The difference between two odd squares is always a multiple of $8$ or some higher power of $2$. So here - knowing that they are of the same parity - we can tell that $c$ and $a$ will both be odd. (The difference between even squares can be an odd multiple of $4$).

It is a question of using all the information in the question and choosing the best starting point. Note that if you were not constrained to positive integers $\pm a, \pm b, \pm c$ would give solutions for all combinations of signs (and sometimes questions a bit like this arise where all the signs are relevant or required).

Comment: I'm still stuck. I managed to get to $(b+a)(b-a) = 33 . 3$ so that $b+a = 33$ and $b-a = 3$ Which made me get $a=15$ and $b=18$ but now $c^2 = (b^2 +1) + 100  $which is not a perfect square.

Comment: I've added some detail to the answer - note you have to use all the information at once, and pick the cases which fit the whole problem. If your case doesn't work, try another possibility.